# How do you panTo your current location using react google maps api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to use a button to pan the google map to the users current location. The panTo is effective but only on number values. I try using the parseFloat method on the values returned by the geolocation, but it doesn't work.

The error I receive is 'not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value', name: 'InvalidValueError', stack: 'Error\n'

```
const AddSpotPage = (props) => {
    const {isLoaded}= useJsApiLoader({
      googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    })

    const [map, setMap]= useState( /** @type google.maps.GoogleMap */ (null))

    **let userLat;
    let userLong;
    let test = {lat: parseFloat(userLat), lng: parseFloat(userLong)}**

    let center = {lat: 50.8584, lng: 12.2945}

    useEffect(()=> {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
        userLat =             
          position.coords.latitude 
        ;
        userLong =             
           position.coords.longitude 
        ;
        console.log(userLat, userLong);
      })
    },[]);

return (
      <div className="pt-5 justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex w-100"
        style={{
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          height: "100vh",
        }}
      >

        <GoogleMap 
        center={center} 
        zoom={15} 
        mapContainerStyle={{width: "80%", height:"80%"}}
        onLoad={map=>setMap(map)}

        </GoogleMap>
        **<button onClick={()=> map.panTo(test)}>Pan Location</button>**

        
      </div>
    );
};

export default AddSpotPage;
```

Comment: When you call `parseFloat(userLat)` you get NaN because `userLat` is `undefined`. A line like `let test = {lat: parseFloat(userLat), lng: parseFloat(userLong)}` does not magically extend into the future, it uses the current values of `userLat` and `userLong`. Those should be part of the state anyway.

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! This helped me get me solution.

Answer (score 2):

Heres the code that worked for me:

```
const[userLat, setUserLat]= useState();
const[userLong, setUserLong]= useState();

useEffect(()=> {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
    setUserLat(position.coords.latitude);
    setUserLong(position.coords.longitude);
    console.log(userLat, userLong);
  })
},[]);
return(
<>
<GoogleMap 
center={center} 
zoom={15} 
mapContainerStyle={{width: "80%", height:"80%"}}
onLoad={map=>setMap(map)}
>

</GoogleMap>
<button onClick={()=> map.panTo({lat:userLat,lng:userLong})}>Pan Location</button>
</>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).